# .NET Core 1.1, xUnit integration with Jenkins Test Result

Tags: jenkins, .net-core, xunit

I have a Jenkins job that runs a unit test step on a .net core project (.net core 1.1) using the following dotnet CLI command: `dotnet test -l trx`.
The Unit Testing framework used is xUnit.

The problem is that the output trx file format is not fully compatible with Jenkins Test Results viewer as the All Tests table has at Package level one row only called "(root)" but beneath it, at "Class" level there is also one row but it has no name making impossible the navigation to the actual test methods beneath it.

I am using XUnitPublisher with MSTestJunitHudsonTestType for publishing the test results:

`step([$class: 'XUnitPublisher', testTimeMargin: '3000', thresholdMode: 1, thresholds: [[$class: 'FailedThreshold', failureNewThreshold: '', failureThreshold: '', unstableNewThreshold: '', unstableThreshold: ''], [$class: 'SkippedThreshold', failureNewThreshold: '', failureThreshold: '', unstableNewThreshold: '', unstableThreshold: '']], tools: [[$class: 'MSTestJunitHudsonTestType', deleteOutputFiles: true, failIfNotNew: true, pattern: /TestResults/*.trx', skipNoTestFiles: false, stopProcessingIfError: true]]])`

Is there a solution to correctly integrate the trx output result with the Jenkins Test Result view?

Answer (score 0):

We use Jenkins and `dotnet test` with trx in https://github.com/dotnet/cli.

We make [this call](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/master/netci.groovy#L63)

```
Utilities.addMSTestResults(newJob, '**/*.trx')
```

That `addMSTestResults` is [implemented here](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-ci/blob/407ddf1e8fadd1d92d28e47a38e70cef1d6ee7ee/jobs/generation/Utilities.groovy#L1121).

You should be able to emulate what we do.